# How to get all records before any specified month in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I want to select all records before any specified month using mysql. Here is my attempted statement:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as allPreviousAmount FROM `fn_table`
WHERE MONTH(transdate) < 1 AND YEAR(transdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

`transdate` is ***datetime*** data type.

I have data on December 2018. But this does not select the data. Then I remove the Year part, still no data is selected. The transdate is 2018-12-31 15:59:41.

Please fix it and explain why this is not working.

Comment: What is the return is it 0?

Comment: the return value is \null

Comment: Are there any months less than 1?

Comment: May be you get my question wrong. That is just my attempt. I just want to select any data before the specified month. In my question I want to get data before January 2019 without the need to select 2018

Comment: Just do `WHERE YEAR(transdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()-1) `

Comment: Using this, I think, I will loss the dynamic. For example If I want to select data before June 2019, how do I do that?

Comment: @phil652 doesn't work if looking for data prior to june 2019 (for example)

Comment: *before any specified month* of the **current** year only?

Comment: Fix you question please, no one knows what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: `WHERE MONTH(transdate) < 1`.  So what do you call month 0 or month -1???  I am never aware such months exist.

Comment: Please add input data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do (assuming there are no future dates):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as allPreviousAmount 
FROM `fn_table`
WHERE MONTH(transdate) < ? OR YEAR(transdate) < YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Replace `?` with the month that you want the results for.

Comment: ? can't be 1 like OP example

Comment: Yes it can be 1.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. So simple and elegant to me.

Comment: @forpas you are right sorry I didn't realized you changed the `AND` to `OR`

Answer (score 2):

Multiply year by 100 add month (on both sides) and compare.

```
set @dt1 = '2019-10-01';

select  @dt1,current_date,
            year(@dt1) * 100 + month(@dt1),
            case 
                when year(@dt1) * 100 + month(@dt1) < year(current_date) * 100 + month(current_date) then
                    'Less than'
                else 'other'
                end as result;

------------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+
| @dt1       | current_date | year(@dt1) * 100 + month(@dt1) | result    |
+------------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+
| 2019-10-01 | 2019-11-14   |                         201910 | Less than |
+------------+--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please can you elaborate it with an example.